# Working of break statement in IF statement nested in FOR

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, loops, for-loop, break

Consider this code:

```
int f=0;
for(......)
{
    ..........
    ..........
    //some code that does not alter f and z
    ..........
    ..........
    double prev = 0; int z = 0; int y = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < c.timesteps; x++)
    {

        for (z=0; z < outs[i].campaigns.ToArray().Length; z++)
        {
            if (x == (outs[i].outage_dates[outs[i].campaigns[z]] * 7))
            {
                f = z;
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nF=" + f);
        Console.Read();
        for (y = f; y < outs[i].campaigns.ToArray().Length; y++)
        {
            .............

            .............

            .............
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute it, the value of z is changing as the IF condition is becoming true. But the value of f is always zero. It should be change to value of z when condition is true. The value of z can only be zero when it leaves the last loop and continues the top loop.

Anyone please tell me What is wrong with this code? Am I applying some wrong logic?

**Update:**

Guys problem is solved everything was working fine. Just I was unable to see it clearly. I displayed each and every variables' value on console (values of f and z) and I saw that its working fine. Apologies for it.

Comment: I'd suggest putting a breakpoint (press F9) on the `double prev = 0;...` line and stepping through the code line by line (F10).

Comment: Have you checked with debugger if the line `f = z;` is ever hit? I mean - have you checked if the condition is `true` anytime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The value of z can only be zero when it leaves the last loop and
>   continues the top loop.

No, Value of `z` would be `0` in the first iteration of inner for loop and if during the first iteration the condition is met then `f` will be assigned `0` and it will keep `0` till the rest. Or if the condition is never met then `f` will keep its old value which is again `0`